# Difference between page and paged

Tags: custom-post-types, pagination

I have created a CPT that has an archive. When it comes to navigate between the pages, I have to use the page querystring like the snippet below.

```
$current = get_query_var('page') ? get_query_var('page') : 1; // Get query var
```

If I do use the paged one, for some reason my archive pages end up to generate a 404 error and I can't figure this out.
Can you please explain?

Thanks
Andrea

Comment: What theme are you using?

Comment: I've built my own theme, but I started from WP examples. So I'm not really reinvenitng the wheel.

Answer (score 1):

`$paged` is the query parameter controlling which page of posts is returned per page. `$page` is a parameter controlling which page to display of a post broken apart by `<!--nextpage-->` tags.

You can switch to the default permalinks and just read this out of the URL.

Comment: So both of them are not related to the "pagination" implemented by the paginate_links() function. So is it correct to have a "page" parameter in that case?

Comment: `paginate_links()` will use whatever variable you tell it to. It is a flexible function, but it is best ___not___ to use a variable already potentially in use by WordPress.